# retrieve user from database from javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am making an application in Laravel and I need to retrieve a user from the database from javascript, from its id.

Something like:
User :: find (id);
or:
DB :: table ('users') -> find (id);

but in javascript

Comment: Write a Laravel endpoint / route that sends JSON, and request it from JS using XMLHttpRequest / fetch ( / axios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using AJAX.

```
your other JS code
...

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "to your controller",
data: {
'user_id' : user_id,
},


success: function (data) {
userdata1 = data.data1;
userdata2 = data.data2;
...something


}
});
```

And the controller would look something like this

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
public function somefunction(Request $request)
{

$user = User::find($request->user_id);
... do other stuff


return response()->json([
    'data1' => someValue1;
     'data2' => someValue2;
]);


}
}
```

If you only need User's data, you can simply use route model binding and

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
public function somefunction(User $user)
{


return response()->json([
    'data1' => $user->name;
    'data2' => $user->addr;
]);


}
}
```

There might be a better solution, but it works.

Don't know how exactly your code is, but if User's data has been already sent to view from controller, you can just do

```
var x = "<?php echo $user->somedata ?>"
```

in you JS code